# What is this type of option menu called in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

[click to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76ahz.jpg)

[image]

what it is called and how to make it.

Comment: It's an Alert dialog box with a Custom View,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a custom dialog. Custom dialogs are implemented by extending the `Dialog` class and using your own layout by this way:

```
class CustomDialog extends Dialog {
    
    // default constructor
    public CustomDialog(Activity activity) { // activity that runs your dialog
        super(activity);
    }
        
    // default onCreate method
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            
        // set your custom dialog layout here
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout);
    
        // your code here
    }
}
```